# juju not responding

Tags: juju, snap

Some sort of mess I have made by not properly cleaning resources under juju, so after that any other command but "juju controllers" would stuck and not responding.

How to delete those rather non existing controllers from the list reported?

```
$ juju controllers
Use --refresh option with this command to see the latest information.

Controller  Model    User              Access     Cloud/Region         Models  Nodes    HA  Version
alter-ego   default  admin             superuser  localhost/localhost       1      1  none  2.9-beta1    
osm-k8s     osm      admin             superuser  microk8s/localhost        2      -     -  2.9-beta1  
osm-lxd*    default  admin             superuser  localhost/localhost       2      1  none  2.8.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
juju destroy-controller --help
```

This can be a good start. It gives you additional options like:

```
--destroy-all-models
```

and

```
--destroy-storage  or --release-storage
```

Examples:
# Destroy the controller and all hosted models. If there is
# persistent storage remaining in any of the models, then
# this will prompt you to choose to either destroy or release
# the storage.
juju destroy-controller --destroy-all-models mycontroller

```
# Destroy the controller and all hosted models, destroying
# any remaining persistent storage.
juju destroy-controller --destroy-all-models --destroy-storage

# Destroy the controller and all hosted models, releasing
# any remaining persistent storage from Juju's control.
juju destroy-controller --destroy-all-models --release-storage
```